# servlet response time is slow for first request

Tags: java, class, servlets, web-applications

`Servlet` response time slow only for 1st request

**Response time**

1st `request` is 10.5 seconds.

further `request` 2.5 seconds.

From few `java` resources i got to know that the `servlet` loads the required `classes` for the first time during the first `request` and reuses the same for further `requests` and hence the `delay`

**Fix 1:** 
I created a `dummy request` within the `servlet` immediately after the execution of `init()` method.

Response time : 2.5 seconds for all requests through user agents.

**Fix 2:**
I tried loading possible `classes` in the `startup` of `servlet`

Response time : for first `request` is 6 seconds. 2.5 seconds for other requests.

Is there are any other possibility of achieving the same because i believe that **method 1** needs code change when there is a change in the url of the application (port number, resource path, etc) and response time of **method 2** is not sufficient.

I have already set `loadOnStartup=1` for my `servlet`.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use load-on-startup param in  web.xml to load and intitiliaze your servlet on starttime.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>My Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>com.foo.MyServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```