# Jersey+Grizzly load-on-startup without web.xml

Tags: java, jersey, web.xml, grizzly

according to this ([servlet response time is slow for first request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548778/servlet-response-time-is-slow-for-first-request)) SO Question I can use the `load-on-startup` parameter in web.xml to create the services classes on startup and not on the first client request, which causes better first-response times for clients.

However I'm using Grizzly+Jersey, how can I configure this behaviour in grizzly, or is this completetly impossible? Then what would be alternatives to grizzly without using a full blown Java EE Application Server

EDIT: Main main method is this:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    //Packages which contain service classes
   final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig()
            .packages("de.danielr1996.flamingoapi.services");

    //Logging Aktivieren
    rc.register(new LoggingFilter());

    //Dependency Injection konfigurieren
    rc.register(new DependencyBinder());

    //Jackson hinzufügen
    rc.register(JacksonFeature.class);

    //Datenbank initialisieren
    DatabaseUtil.getEntityManagerFactory();

    // Server erstellen
    return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
        ServletAdapter adapter =new ServletAdapter();
        ...
        adapter.setProperty( "load-on-startup", 1 );
```

**UPDATE**

I don't now how to configure instance created from Factory. I assume it does not allow you to provide complex configuration. 
But you can create server manually this way :

```
GrizzlyWebServer ws = new GrizzlyWebServer(80);
ServletAdapter adapter = new ServletAdapter();
```

Then configure adapter [Javadocs](https://javadocs.com/docs/com.sun.grizzly/grizzly-comet-webserver/1.9.19-beta7/com/sun/grizzly/http/servlet/ServletAdapter.java)

```
adapter.setContextPath("...");      
adapter.setRootFolder("...");
adapter.setHandleStaticResources(true);
adapter.setProperty("load-on-startup","1");
```

Add adapter to server

```
   ws.addGrizzlyAdapter(adapter, new String[]{"/uri"});
```

Comment: Where do put this (My main method is in the question now)?

Comment: @danielr1996 Updated