# Dropwizard response time is slow for first request

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am using dropwizard 1.0.2. I am observing the response time for the very first request is about 5.5 seconds and then the subsequent request is taking about 1 seconds.

The issue is something similar to the one discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548778/servlet-response-time-is-slow-for-first-request).

Can some one let me know if is this expected? If yes then is there a workaround?

If this is not expected can some one let me know how can I log the timings of various phases of request processing in dropwizard?

I have already verified the timings in my resource class (this is returning the response in about 800 ms)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Dropwizard` uses lazy initialization for the resource classes. 
You could add a breakpoint on the constructor of your resource to check if it's called during the startup or on the first request.